# How to enable tracking age and sex using google analytics in Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking

i have turned on 'tracking age and sex' on admin page, also set mTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true); in my code but it seems not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure? about your question

Comment: @M D - Please explain further about your comment?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using google analytics , navigate to **Audience** --> **Demographics**

then navigate between **age** and **gender** to enable them

[image]

after you finish you will get your desired data

Hope this help

Comment: Many thanks, but i have enabled them. I did see nothing.

Comment: follow instruction and you have to wait 24 hour from enabiling https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en